# Receive tracking equipment faulty string

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm developing a socket server that will receive data from a Chinese tracking equipment, the TK-06A. So did my server that is receiving the following information:

```
 ï¿½Lï¿½l}ï¿½8ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
```

What do you think you can be? What enconde I use to resolve this question?
Below my code I'm using to test.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        InputStream input = null;
        int charsRead = 0;
        //Criando um servidor que atendera na porta 8080
        int port = 5016;
        char[] inputChars = new char[1024];
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Aguardando conexao!!!");
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(isr);
                int data = 0;
                System.out.println("Reading from stream:");
                if ((charsRead = inputStream.read(inputChars)) != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Chars read from stream: " + charsRead);
                    System.out.println(inputChars);
                    System.out.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should supply the encoding parameter, otherwise it defaults to the current operating system encoding = non-portable.

```
InputStreamReader isr =
    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), encoding);
```

As encoding one could try `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` (Charset), `UTF_16LE` and the Chinese BIG encodings (as String).

The class `InputStreamReader` is the bridge from binary data (`InputStream, byte[]`) to text (`Reader, String, char`) - which in java always is Unicode, to mix all scripts.